# MySQL: which API to use?

Tags: mysql, api

I'm just getting started with interfacing to MySQL from a C++ app. The app is pretty simple: it's a Linux web server, and the C++ code retrieves JavaScript from a local database to return to the client via Apache and Ajax. The database will contain no more than a few thousand short JavaScript programs.

Question: any advice on which API I should use? I'm just reading through the docs on dev.mysql.com, and there doesn't seem to be any good reason to choose one or other of libmysql, Connector/C, Connector/C++, MySQL++, or Connector/ODBC. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With no more than a few thousand rows, chances are, you should pick your API after your language preferences, not the other way round - so go aheead and chose whatever fits your mood.

If your app's performance stands and falls with the performance differences of the MySQL connectors you should be quite busy fixing your design elsewhere.

I personally prefer portability, so I tend to use a lot of ODBC, accepting the small performance hit, but others might think different. If you never ever want to use a different RDBMS stay away from ODBC - without the portability benefit it's quite ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the raw C API. Seems to be the simplest way with the least overhead.